# Exchange of the underlying data of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas version < 1.1.0 allowed to replace the underlying data of an existing DataFrame. We used this to return a empty dataframe from a context manager and fill in the data later:

```py
class AnalyzerRecordContext():
    def __init__(self, analyzer):
        self._analyzer = analyzer

    def __enter__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        return self.df  # return empty dataframe

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        try:
            df = self._analyzer.stop()  # Returns a complete dataframe
            self.df._data = df._data    # fill returned dataframe
        finally:
            del self._analyzer

# Example Usage
with analyzer.start() as df: # analyzer.start() returns the above Context Manager
  ... Some Code

df.plot()  # DataFrame is now filled with data which was recorded within the context manager
```

Starting with pandas version 1.1.0, this is no longer possible, as the line `self.df._data = df._data` leads to an AttributeError: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

- Is there an alternative way to get to the same result using the public pandas API?
- Is there a better solution in general for this problem?

**UPDATE**:
Searching through the pandas issue tracker, if found [issue #33333](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33333) which mentions the deprecation of the `_data` attribute. The attribute was renamed to `_mgr`, hovever the behaviour seems to have changed too. The index is no longer populated for example. So the questions above still hold.

Answer (score 0):

So actually this is a lot easier, and the method described above is overcomplicated. There is no need to access internal (private) members of the dataframe to acomplish this. Any of the following methods work:

Copy Column by Column:

```py
df1 = ... # Original Dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame()  # The empty dataframe
for col in df1.columns:
    df2[col] = df1[col]
```

Copy all Columns at once:

```py
df1 = ... # Original Dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame()  # The empty dataframe
# Explicit column specification on both dataframes
df2[df1.columns] = df1[df1.columns]
# Column specification only on the new dataframe:
df2[df1.columns] = df1
```